# Change the displayed column in datatables for reference field

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I have some tables with id and descriptive data. In an additional table these tables are referenced.

```
Table A
id int (key)
name string
description string


Table B
id int (key)
name string
description string

Table mix
id_A FK(id tableA)
id_B FK(id tableB)
```

If i now create a datatable for the mix table

```
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.mixController
```

all fields (name and description) of table A and B are shown.

1) How can I change this that only the name is shown?

2) It seems that filtering on the reference columns is not working? I get an exception:
org.gvnix.web.datatables.util.DatatablesUtils - Exception preparing filter for entity

Comment: about the exception... can you get more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to modify the a entity representation is customize its `toString` method. By default, Spring Roo generates this as template using a Apache Commons utility which uses reflections to generate a *representation string*. This method is generated by `@RooToString` annotation and you can found it in the `{entityClass}_Roo_ToString.aj` file. To customize it just *push-in* (see [Spring Roo documentation about it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html#removing-step-by-step-1)) the method.

About the error, as I comment on your question, we need more information to identify the problem. Please, copy some lines of stack trace.

Regards,
Chema.

Comment: It doesn't work to me, I pushed in, and debugged the method toString but never got inside of this method, I saw in the webmvc-config.xml this bean:  `<bean class="org.gvnix.web.datatables.util.impl.DatatablesUtilsBeanImpl" id="datatableUtilsBean"/>` maybe this is who control the fields to be displayed by the datatable?

Comment: Also check the `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` and its related _.aj_ files. `DatatablesUtilsBean` should use it to make conversions of types.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the source code of the controller I realized the controllers retrieve data to datatables trough the method datatablesUtilsBean_dtt.populateDataSet and it use the autowired property conversionService annotation.

So in order to change the value of the displayed field is necessary to modify the controller class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean in the converter methods for example:

```
getMixToStringConverter()
```

where Mix is the table converting to string and the return value of this method is the String representation of your entity.
you could change your method like this to only show the name:

```
return new StringBuilder().append(mix.getTableA().getName).append(mix.getTableB().getName()).toString();
```